# Is there any way to get the TriggeredBy value inside the release pipeline in Azure Devops

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-pipelines

i want to receive the Triggered By value inside the Azure release pipeline [TriggeredBy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x3CHA.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [predefined variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=batch#default-variables---release): `Release.RequestedFor` , `Release.TriggeringArtifact.Alias`

**Release.RequestedFor**:   The display name of identity that triggered the release.
Example: Mateo Escobedo

**Release.TriggeringArtifact.Alias**: The alias of the artifact which triggered the release. This is empty when the release was scheduled or triggered manually.
Example: fabrikam_app

Answer (score 0):

We could add task **Bash** and enter the script `printenv` to list all variable. And it contain a variable `RELEASE_REASON` and `RELEASE_REQUESTEDFOR`

`RELEASE_REASON` show the create release method

[image]

`RELEASE_REQUESTEDFOR` show the user display name who trigger this release.

[image]

Comment: In the Initialize job step all these variables are already printed. No need to add a Bash task.